# How to remove horizontal recyclerview(child) inside the recyclerview(parent) scroll to first position when notifyitemchange?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview, notifyitemchanged

I am using multiple view type inside the recyclerview. In which one of the view type is recyclerview of linear layoutmanager with horizontal orientation. I loaded all view type inside the parent recyclerview. When I change the some item in horizonatal recyclerview item of position 10 and update by `adapter?.notifyItemChanged(10)`, the horizonatal recyclerview jump to first position 0. And it creates a bad user experience.

Also I used `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` and `setHasFixedSize(true)` in parent and child Recyclerview not does not works. Is there is any way to solve my problem. And also attached image for reference [image]

Here position 1 is horizonal recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

You could save the `RecyclerView`'s layout instance and restore post notifying `adapter`, this will restore layout manager properties like scroll position

```
val savedInstance = recyclerView.layoutManager?.onSaveInstanceState()
adapter?.notifyItemChanged(10)
recyclerView.layoutManager?.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstance)
```